# Add a filter to view answer body with StackAPI for Python

Tags: python-3.x, stackexchange-api

I am using StackAPI (python wrapper) to extract data from Stack Oveflow. Everything works perfectly except when trying to add a filter.

```
SITE = StackAPI('stackoverflow', key=<my_key>)
answers = SITE.fetch('questions/{ids}/answers?filter=!9_bDE(fI5', ids=[int(q_id)])
```

I created the filter using the StackExchange API's filter edit function and copied it.

The `fetch` works perfectly if I remove the `?filter=!9_bDE(fI5'` from end point. But that output is useless as I am interested in the answer body.

Could some one please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing it all wrong. Instead of adding the filter as part of the end point, it should be a parameter.

```
answers = SITE.fetch('questions/{ids}/answers', ids=[int(q_id)], filter='!9_bDE(fI5')
```

This performed as expected.